# Showing php as html by '.htaccess', also php extension will not work

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really need help regarding this. I know that if I add the following line in .htaccess file, php will show as html.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php`

When I write `http://example.org/abc.html`, actually `abc.php` is executing. But when I write `http://example.org/abc.php`, it also works.

Is there anything I can add in the `.htaccess` file where .php will not work. I mean when I will write `abc.html`, `abc.php` will execute. But if I write `abc.php`, it will show 404 error.

Comment: `RedirectMatch 404 \.php$ /path/to/error/document`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 404 \.php$
```

`RedirectMatch` does not match the query string, so this should even redirect `whatever.php?someParam=someValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this rule should redirect .php files to a 404

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php - [R=404]
```

The R=404 part sets the return code to a 404. Here's documentation on the R option: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r. And the "-" means that the URL is passed through untouched.

You'll also need to add this before either of your two redirect rules (taken from http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Fix_infinite_loops):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

This will prevent a redirect loop from happening that will present the user a 404 error when they use the .html extension as well as the .php extension.